# How to add a new qdisc in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to modify the Red Algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_early_detection) for certain experiments. 
After modifying the code, I loaded onto the kernel using the `insmod` command.

I verified the successful loading by using `lsmod | grep red_new`

However when I try to use the tc qdisc command it fails giving the following error:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root red_new limit 100 min 80 max 90 avpkt 10 burst 10 probability 1 bandwidth 200 ecn

unknown qdisc "red_new" hence option "limit" is unparsable
```

What could be the possible reason ?

After running the ltrace command suggested by ymonad I get the following output:

```
strlen("red_new")                                = 7
strlen("red_new")                                = 7
strlen("red_new")                                = 7
strncpy(0x7fff6467ad10, "red_new", 15)           = 0x7fff6467ad10
dlopen("./tc/q_red_new.so", 1)                   = 0x1abe030
dlsym(0x1abe030, "red_new_qdisc_util")           = 0x7f62bdd240c0
memcpy(0x7fff6467ad48, "red_new\0", 8)           = 0x7fff6467ad48
```

I ran the tc qdisc show to check if it was added but it hasn't.

```
 tc qdisc show
qdisc mq 0: dev eth0 root
qdisc mq 0: dev eth1 root
qdisc mq 0: dev eth2 root
qdisc mq 0: dev eth3 root
```

Comment: Have you seen this: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/classless-qdiscs.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the result of `strace tc qdisc add dev eth0 root red_new`, and source of `tc` command, it seems that tc is searching for `$TC_LIB_DIR/q_red_new.so`.

You have to create the module for your own. I would give you small instruction.

(1) Download source of iproute2 from following url, extract it, and `cd` to the folder. 
https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2

(2) Copy `q_red.c` to `q_red_new.c`

```
$ cp tc/q_red.c tc/q_red_new.c
```

(3) Edit tc/q_red_new.c

Rename `red_parse_opt`, `red_print_opt`, `red_print_xstats`, to `red_new_parse` and so on. 
Additionally you have to rename `red_qdisk_util` to `req_new_qdisc_util` and change the `id` and other members.

```
struct qdisc_util red_new_qdisc_util = {
  .id   = "red_new",
  .parse_qopt = red_new_parse_opt,
  .print_qopt = red_new_print_opt,
  .print_xstats = red_new_print_xstats,
};
```

(4) Configure and build `q_red_new.so`

```
$ ./configure
$ make TCSO=q_red_new.so
```

now you see that `./tc/q_red_new.so` is created

(5) Run `tc` command with `TC_LIB_DIR` environment.

```
$ TC_LIB_DIR='./tc' tc qdisc add dev eth0 root red_new
```

UPDATE: here's how to know that the `tc` command loaded the `q_red_new.so` correctly.

if `dlopen` returns zero then you failed to load`./tc/q_red_new.so`.

if `dlsym` returns zero then you failed to load `red_new_qdisc_util` inside the q_red_new.so.

```
# export TC_LIB_DIR='./tc'
# ltrace ./tc/tc qdisc add dev eth0 root red_new limit 100 min 80 max 90 avpkt 10 burst 10 probability 1 bandwidth 200 ecn 2>&1 | grep red_new
.. OMITTED ..
dlopen("./tc/q_red_new.so", 1)                   = 0x12c1030
snprintf("red_new_qdisc_util", 256, "%s_qdisc_util", "red_new") = 18
dlsym(0x12c1030, "red_new_qdisc_util")           = 0x7f1cf0d6cc40
.. OMITTED ..
```

Comment: I followed the steps you mentioned and the q_red_new.so file was created. However I am still facing the same error ! :(

Comment: what's the result of `$ strace bash -c 'TC_LIB_DIR="./tc" tc qdisc add dev eth0 root red_new' 2>&1 | grep q_red_new` ? does `tc` successfully opening `q_red_new.so` ?

Comment: I am getting the following message: open("./tc/q_red_new.so",O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4

Comment: Shouldn't tc command be looking for the red_new.ko file as well ?

Comment: No.`red_new.ko` is loaded by linux kernel with `insmod` command. `tc`   uses some other system call to communicate with linux kernel. Since `open("./tc/q_red_new.so")` is returning non-negative value so you succeeded to open the file. but the error is showing that the `q_red_new.so` is not a valid module for `tc` (maybe the version of tc differs from module ?). I updated the answer so debug it with `ltrace` command.

Comment: I edited my question and added the output of ltrace command. dlopen and dlsym returns memory address!